# yui date time schedule

Tags: yui, schedule

I inspected code of http://timetomeet.info/new/. I would like to make the same time selector as is here at http://timetomeet.info/new/ 
Is there any step by step instruction how to do it? I need output for php to process it (so it should be array with times or something like that).

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Just try to extract all js a yahoo scripts and it works.